# why is Linq way quicker

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to wrap my head around this on why linq tremendously quicker than manual programming.

Scenario 1:

```
Series = _model.Titles
    .Where(t => TempIds.Contains(t.ID))
    .ToList()
    .Select(t => new BaseSeries(t))
    .ToList();
```

Scenario 2

```
foreach (var title in _model.Titles)
{
   if (TempIds.Contains(title.ID))
   {
        Series.Add(new BaseSeries(title));
        TempIds.Remove(title.ID);
        if (TempIds.Count == 0)
            break;
   }
}
```

When I time this out Linq Finishes the query and creates the list in .265s

while the foreach take 2.62s?

Linq is doing an extra cast to list as well.  The First .ToList() is needed to prevent an Linq to entities error. This Table quite large.  Caching has not been implemented yet either so its not cache.

How is Linq been optimized that it finishes 10 times quicker?

Comment: they should be comparable. you might try removing the `.Remove` and the following `if` statements, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why do you create two lists in scenario1? Apart from that you filter in the database in sc1. whereas you load **all** into memory first and filter there in sc2.

Comment: The .Remove Makes the foreach quicker Because once it finds all of the ids in the list it breaks out of the loop which prevents it from iterating overall of the contents of the _model.Titles Table.   Removing the removing will make it take longer

Comment: The First List is a hack because "only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in linq to entities"  So by casting it to a List First you are doing Linq to Object which does not have the same constraint.  The Second ToList() is to put it into a List for Series

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
_model.Titles.Where(t => TempIds.Contains(t.ID))
```

This line will only pull records from the database that match the criteria.

```
foreach (var title in _model.Titles)
```

Whilst this pull the entire table in the database, and perform the filtering after the records  are converted into objects. Hence the differences.

---

The underlying queries for these two may look like :

```
-- _model.Titles.Where(t => TempIds.Contains(t.ID))
select * from Title where TempIds like '%' + ID + '%'

-- foreach (var title in _model.Titles)
select * from Title
```

Comment: Are you saying that the linq Version occurs on the SQL Side so you don't have the overhead for importing and creating the objects in C# to the manually check the titles after?

Comment: +1.  @user1938988 You should spend some time diving into deferred execution and how that translates to the query being executed on the server instead of in memory.